# What happens if there is no beehive in my Terraria world?

Tags: terraria-console

[image]So I was looking for a beehive in my world and I couldn't find one, is there any solutions to this? How do I craft an Abeemanation?

Comment: Can you do a screenshot? That photo is really low quality.

Comment: I cant because I'm on mobile for this

Comment: What was the "XB1" supposed to mean in the title if you play on mobile?

Comment: On mobile of this website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to search a much bigger portion of the underground jungle. The beehives are only around 30 blocks tall and 15 blocks wide and the underground jungle is very very big.

Comment: Oke, I'll do that

Answer (score 2):

Every world should have a beehive - if you haven't found one then you haven't discovered the entire jungle. If impatient, you can simply create a new LARGE world, find the jungle, and hunt around that for a beehive.

Comment: But my world is a large world and there is no openings that I havent discovered in my jungle

Comment: Jungles in large worlds take up a huge amount of space and it looks like you've discovered a total of 3 lines. Try digging through the walls.